Webcomic where an office worker gets isekai-ed into a world that thinks she’s a witch because of her black eyes
A (female) office worker (?) is tired from her day at work and she gets in the elevator to leave her job (I’m assuming she dies). So the next scene is a lady that looks like her but with longer (?) hair running away from a group of people. The group of people claim that she is a witch because she has black eyes. She eventually finds a brothel and begs to hide; the owner (male) allows her to. She hides in a bed (bunk?) with Curtains, that (turns out to have a prince laying in there?). Then she and him have to pretend that they are having sex.
Later, the prince is like “Ieaaah, I'mma take you (the witch)” and so he does and then, they travel back to the main part of the kingdom, the girl gets put in a cell for a bit (she is in very revealing clothing); he forces himself on her.
Then they go to see the royal family; the prince is claiming to marry the witch girl and the family is pissed. The royal family talks of disgust because they already have a planned set up marriage with another kingdom.
The royal family have three sons (including the prince).
The comic shows adult content.

Is this some type of manga/manhwa/manhua? And was it full colour or mostly black & white? Also, do you recall the hair colour of the female lead and/or the male lead?

All I remember is the FL might have had black/dark hair and she had black styled eyes.
But the it was in black and white.

Black eyes as in entirely black?

No, I pretty sure it’s just normal black comic eyes

Any idea where you read this? Was this a manga?

I think mangastic or manga chill…

Isekai no Boukun Outaishi ni Metorare Soudesu!?: Tensei Majo wa Kuroki Ookami ni Kyuuaisareru aka The Tyrant Crown Prince From Another World Wants To Marry Me!? -The Black Wolf Courts The Reincarnated Witch by ENVY


After meeting an unfortunate accident and losing consciousness, corporate slave Yuki wakes up in a fantasy world! Thinking she'd live a dazzling new life in a new land, she's instead hunted by scoundrels and takes refuge in a brothel. She finds herself in even more danger, though, as she's called a witch! Just then, the mysterious knight Matias comes to her rescue. However, he expects her body in return. His aggressive kisses and sweet caresses have her swept up in the pleasure. Matias takes an interest in her boldness and reveals that he's the crown prince! He passionately proposes, wanting Yuki for himself...!


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as quotes, matching details form the original question, or a synopsis. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@Derpy - Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as accepted by clicking on the grey check mark on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Fair warning that, as might be guessed from the cover image, this is a fairly explicit manga.
